# Extend external class prototype/type definition with custom function (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype, ws

I'm trying to extend a class (from an external websocket library) with a custom function by adding my function to the prototype. But i'm get the `Property 'customFuction' does not exist on type 'WebSocket'` error which is understandable.

```js
import WebSocket from "ws";

WebSocket.prototype.customFunction = function customFunction(): void {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
"Property 'customFuction' does not exist on type 'WebSocket'
};
```

But my question is how do I add my function to the existing class definition?
I don't want to create a new type (like `MyWebSocket extends WebSocket`) because I want the method to be available on the WebSocket class.

---

Edit: I also tried the solution below suggested by @Balastrong but this still doesn't work. I'm also using the `@types/ws` package for the type definitions but I don't think module augmentation updates those definitions, could this be the reason for why this solution isn't working?

```js
// WebSocketExtensions.ts
import WebSocket from "ws";

declare module "ws" {
  export interface WebbSocket {
    customFunction(): void;
  }
}

WebSocket.prototype.customFunction = () => console.log('Hey');
```

Comment: `WebSocket` is the default export of the `ws` module. Your augmented module declares an additional named export.

Comment: Probably you just need to remove the `export` keyword (and fix the misspelling), so that `interface WebSocket` extends the declaration from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ws/index.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

Typescript allows to [merge interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) so that if there are multiple interfaces with the same name, they're merged as if they were one.

You can declare your method to a `WebSocket` interface inside a `declare global`, then you can add your prototype.

```js
declare global {
  export interface WebSocket {
    customFunction: () => void;
  }
}

WebSocket.prototype.customFunction = () => console.log('Hey');
```

---

If you get an error on global like `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)` you need to add `export {};` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: OP doesn't modify the global `WebSocket` available in browsers, they extend the export of the `ws` library

Comment: …but yes, declaration merging is the way to go, in particular https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Comment: I tried you suggestion (see updated question) but it still doesn't work. I'm also using `@types/ws`  for the type definitions for `ws` could this be the reason why I cant augment the `WebSocket` class?